# presentViewController not called when webview presents ImagePicker

Tags: ios, webview, uiimagepickercontroller

I've seen a couple questions that elude to the function `presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion{` should be called when imagepicker is shown due to `UIWebView` calling it.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion{

   if([viewControllerToPresent.class isEqual:[UIImagePickerController class]]){
       UIImagePickerController *controller = (UIImagePickerController*)viewControllerToPresent;

       controller.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
       [controller.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
        @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
       [controller.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
       [controller.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
   }

   [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewController` that holds your web view will call that method when you use an `<input type="file">` tag in your web view and click the resulting button.

This method is already implemented in `UIViewController`, but if you want to override it, you can do so on your `UIViewController` subclass.  In swift:

```
override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
```

In Objective-C:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
}
```

It's worth noting that the controller that's presented when I test this on an iOS11 simulator is not a `UIImagePickerController` but in fact a `UIDocumentMenuViewController`, so your custom code above would not work.

Also, just as a note, you shouldn't be using `UIWebView` anymore.  You should instead be using `WKWebView`.

Comment: Couple things, when i use WKWebview my imagepicker controller doesn't have a done button so i switched back to uiwebview, WKWebview also has a bunch of issues with cookies, and wasn't keeping my user logged in. Secondly, the UIDoucmentController is shown when presenting the 2 choices, than once you click photo library, an imagepicker is shown. The override function presentViewController is never called when the <input type="file"> is clicked via uiwebview.

Comment: UIWebView is going away.  You need to figure out a way to work with WKWebView. As to the call, you aren't seeing the call when you choose because it's being called on the UIDocumentMenuViewController not on your VC.  YourVC presents the UIDocumentMenuViewController which presents the UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 0):

The event will be called on your ROOT view, which may or may not be your WebViewController.  Use the layout inspector to find your root view, or retrieve the root view programmatically from the app delegate.